# How to test specific elements of a Create-React-App (in TypeScript) with react testing library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, create-react-app, react-testing-library

I generated a project using create-react-app with the --typescript option.

This is my app:

```
import React from 'react';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div>
            <h1 id="pageHeader">Home page</h1>
            <p>This is the Home page</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

My current test is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import App from './App';

test('Verify page header', () => {
    const {getByText} = render(<App/>);
    expect(getByText('Home page')).toBeInTheDocument;
});
```

**The question:**
I want to test a little more. Besides testing if "Home page" occurs anywhere in my page, I want to make sure that the text "Home Page" is located in the h1 element. How do I get the full element (preferably via getElementById) from the react-testing-library so I can do assertions on it with Jest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points, based on your own answer:

1. You should avoid any logic branches in tests. Logic in tests can lead to flaky tests, since the logic in the test isn't tested. In your case, the `if` blocks are unnecessary, since the test will already fail if the text content doesn't exist.
2. There are a couple of simple ways to test that the text "Home Page" is in the `h1`:

Find the text and expect the element to be `h1`:

```
test('Verify page header', () => {
    const {getByText} = render(<App/>);
    expect(getByText('Home page').tagName).toBe('H1');
});
```

Or give the `h1` a `data-testid` and use `getByTestId`:

```
<h1 data-testid="pageHeader">Home Page</h1> // <-- In your component

test('Verify page header', () => {
    const {getByTestId} = render(<App/>);
    expect(getByTestId('pageHeader').textContent).toBe('Home Page');
});
```

Comment: Do you know why there is a method for getByTestId but not for getById? I was looking on the internet for a reason but I don't understand why we simply can't use the id. Adding data-testid's to code just for tests feels weird.

Comment: I don't have a great explanation for you, but the `react-testing-library` author has some thoughts about using `id` vs `data-testid` in this thread: https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/183 He also links to a blog article: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/making-your-ui-tests-resilient-to-change

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it like this:

```
test('Verify page header', () => {
    const {container} = render(<App/>);
    const pageHeaderElement = container.querySelector('#pageHeader');
    if (pageHeaderElement) {
        const pageHeaderElementContent = pageHeaderElement.firstChild;
        if (pageHeaderElementContent) {
            // You can either do:
            expect(pageHeaderElementContent.textContent).toMatch('Home page');
            // Or:
            expect(pageHeaderElementContent).toMatchInlineSnapshot('Home page');
        } else {
            fail('Should have existed.');
        }
    } else {
        fail('Should have existed.');
    }
});
```

I found out about this toMatchInlineSnapshot method in the documentation of react-testing library:
https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#render

Shorter version with the new TypeScript optional chaining:

```
test('Verify page header', () => {
    const {container} = render(<App/>);
    const pageHeaderContent = container.querySelector("#pageHeader")?.firstChild?.textContent;
    expect(pageHeaderContent).toMatch('Home page');
});
```